# Is there another way (other than LAMP) to test a .php prestashop website on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

I tried the lamp mode but it doesn't work. When I type the url http://localhost/prestashop/public_html/
It shows some text file with the license. Is there another way to test .php websites on linux? 
Thanks

Comment: Hello, just doing a follow up. Did you get this working?

Comment: Hey sorry I was not at work, just came to see this today. I tried doing what you said and it said Listening on http://localhost:8000
Document root is /home/morgoth
Press Ctrl-C to quit.

Comment: Yes, correct. That is what we wanted. Then go to that link (Url) and see if your app come up as you expect.

Comment: I went to localhost:8000 and it said 404 not found. (Not Found
The requested resource / was not found on this server. )Additionally, as I was doing that, the console showed a bunch of errors: [Tue Jul 18 10:20:43 2017] 127.0.0.1:50028 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Tue Jul 18 10:20:44 2017] 127.0.0.1:50032 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory

Comment: Your doing something incorrectly with your install. Follow this guide at http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu and dump your html files in /var/www/html directory. It works, I've used it many times.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information to answer this question.
Does not sound like you have everything setup correctly.

A [LAMP install](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu) is usually very easy . After the setup, the default folder should be /var/www/html to drop the files in to. Then we have the issue with the Presta Shop.

Usually for Drupal, Joomla, Shopping Cart, Etc... software a link is provided and when you go to that url link it checks and see's if it thinks all the requirements pass: PHP, Apache, mysql or other database, etc... then it will complete the install and setup and provide a admin url and a guest/user/shopper url.

If everything is already setup correctly it should work, but you can go to the directory of your prestashop http://localhost/prestashop/public_html and from a command prompt run :
php -S localhost:8000
That command will run and show a url link in the terminal, right click and open that link. You should again, see prestashop if it was installed correctly.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678010/php-server-on-local-machine

Your doing something incorrectly with your install. Follow this guide at http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu and dump your html files in /var/www/html directory. It works, I've used it many times.

You also need to read the prestashop guide better. Apache and PHP based apps like prestashop, drupal, joomla, etc... are tested tried and true. 
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Installing+PrestaShop

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I did the steps mentioned in your first link. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: When you say "drop the files" , what do you mean exactly? I have a cpanel full backup here, and here is what it has inside.  http://imgur.com/a/SdZ5k Homedir is what I have put in ww

Comment: Copy all files and folders you want on website to that folder.